# failed to read dockerfile: open /var/lib/docker/tmp/buildkit-mount3324381401/Dockerfile

Tags: python, docker, dockerfile, git-bash

while I am trying to build docker.

I am getting this error. Can somebody help? I am using windows and `mingw64`

```
ERROR: failed to solve: failed to read dockerfile: open /var/lib/docker/tmp/buildkit-mount3324381401/Dockerfile
```

Btw, I using docker file is named `DockerFile`, and this is what it contains

```
FROM python:3.9-alpine3.13
LABEL maintaner="xxx"

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
COPY ./requirements.txt /tmp/requirements.txt
COPY ./app /app
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 8000

RUN python -m venv /py && \
    /py/bin/pip install --upgrade pip && \
    /py/bin/pip install -r /tmp/requirements/txt && \
    rm -rf /tmp && \
    adduser \
        --disabled-password \
        --no-create-home \
        django-user
ENV PATH="/py/bin:$PATH"

USER django-use
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F4wxJ.png)

I tried to build the docker, but I was getting the error shown above.

Comment: The filename `Dockerfile` needs a lowercase `f`.

Comment: Please provide a list of steps required to reproduce this. Make sure each step is actually needed, see [mcve] for context. As a new user here, also take the [tour] and read [ask]. Also, where it says "enter image description here", you are supposed to fill that in!